# Select multiple words in a text box and track them in C#

Tags: c#, select, textbox

Is it possible to select multiple words(for eg: "The **family** live in a **big** house") and track those selected words?

If possible, how can i do it?

Edit----

I need to select the words using the mouse and put those selected words in a string array.

Comment: could you evaluate? how would you like to select them. Do you need to find in the text all words that are in some kind of dictionary -> and then list them?

Comment: No actually what I need to do is, select some words in a text box using the mouse and put them (the selected) in a string array.

Comment: Then it's obvious you should be looking at some client side JS that would enable you to store somehow the selection's that they would be visible to you on the code side. Preferably a hidden field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the MouseUp-Event and the SelectedText-Property?

```
List<string> _Words;
private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.DeepPink;
    _Words.Add(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a rich text box and set a highlighting background for each selection (similar to how IE, Firefox, etc will highlight all of the found search terms).  You would have to scan the text and insert the highlighting yourself.  You wouldn't be able to use the builtin selection properties of a textbox since the text isn't contiguous.